# TikZ library automata using option double with shorten

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I'm trying to draw an automata using TikZ and the library `automata`. An accepting state I would like to denote by a double circle but the distance between the two circles should be larger than the default (which is initially `0.6pt`). I do this by setting `double distance=1.5pt` but this does not play nicely together with the option `shorten >=1pt` as seen in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt]
  \node[state] (1) {1};
  \node[state,accepting] (2) [below=of 1] {2};
  \path[->] (1) edge (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,accepting/.style={double distance=1.5pt}]
  \node[state] (1) {1};
  \node[state,accepting] (2) [below=of 1] {2};
  \path[->] (1) edge (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,accepting/.style={double distance=1.5pt}]
  \node[state] (1) {1};
  \node[state,accepting] (2) [below=of 1] {2};
  \path[->,shorten >=1.9pt] (1) edge (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the second automata the arrow touches the double circle of the accepting state. I can manually fix the problem by adding the missing `0.9pt` to the shorten parameter but this is somehow tedious and error prone. Is there some automagically way how to handle this situation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just last week had to handle this in a paper myself... :)  Add the option `outer sep=.9pt` in your definition of `accepting/.style`, which essentially adds a .9pt margin around your accepting nodes.  The `shorten` will be measured from that additional margin.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `outer sep` should be set to half the `double distance` plus `\pgflinewidth`, so for example `accepting/.style={double distance=1.5pt, outer sep=0.75pt+\pgflinewidth`}`. That way, an arrow without `shorten` will end at the outer edge of the double line node in the same way it would for a single line node.

Comment: Thanks Ben and Jake! The problem is solved now. Having it done automatically is much easier and less painfull ;)