# Creating an edge command with iteration

Tags: diagrams, xparse

i intent to create the command `\graphEdge` to streamline drawing graphs edges, it would take a list of arguments separated by `,` the function would then divide the arguments and iterate on it, creating a new `\draw` for each minus the last one.

On the mwe there is some very rough idea of the function implementation, and an example of usage.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentCommand\graphEdge{
    s % #1 - dashed
    > {\SplitList{,}}
    o % #2 - position options
    > {\SplitList{,}}
    o % #3 - draw options
    >{\SplitList{,}}
    m % #4 - annotations
    >{\SplitList{,}}
    m % #5 - nodes
}{
    % i = interator
    \IfValueT{#5[i+1]}{
        \draw[->,\IfBooleanT{#1}{dashed,}\IfValueT{#3[i]}{#3[i]}]%
        (#5[i]-x) --node[sloped,\IfValueTF{#2[i]}{#2[i]}{above}] {\(#4[i]\)}%
        (#5[i+1]-x);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % ======================= Nodes ====================== %

    % 1,2,3
    \node (1-x) at (0, 0) {1};
    \node (2-x) at (1, 1) {2};
    \node (3-x) at (2, 1) {3};
    \node (4-x) at (1,-1) {4};

    % ======================= Edges ====================== %

    % \graphEdge{A,B}{1,2,3}
    \draw[->] (1-x) --node[sloped,above]{\(A\)} (2-x);
    \draw[->] (2-x) --node[sloped,above]{\(B\)} (3-x);
    % \graphEdge*{C,D}{1,4,3}
    \draw[->,dashed] (1-x) --node[sloped,above]{\(C\)} (4-x);
    \draw[->,dashed] (4-x) --node[sloped,above]{\(D\)} (3-x);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of your command, wouldn't be `\graphEdge{[below]A, [above]B}{1, 2, 3}` nicer? With the `graphs` library you can just do `graph[use existing nodes] {1 ->["A"] 2 ->["B"'] 3}` and you see directly which node is placed along which edge.

Comment: I wish that was a solution, i had a whole problem and in the end gave up on that, you can have a look at the progress [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686785/how-to-draw-the-following-image-using-tikz-and-tikz-graphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `l3clist`'s `\clist_item:nn` to access elements in a list directly, since it will be returned with an `\unexpanded`, we can safely use the `.expanded` handler to allow fore more than one option per item (otherwise, it would try to find the key `blue, '` in the example below).

The elements of `#4` is used directly as the list for one `\foreach` loop where `\i` counts from 1 and `\j` counts from 2, though you can just use `\i + 1` and `l3clist` will evaluate that for you.

Instead of setting `above` by default, I'm using `auto = left` which can be `swap`ped to `auto = right` by using the `'` key. (Although, you can set `above` and just define `'/.style = below` just for your nodes.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\graphEdge{
    s % #1 - dashed
    o % #2 - position options
    o % #3 - draw options
    m % #4 - annotations
    m % #5 - nodes
}{
  \foreach[count=\i,count=\j from 2]\VALUE in {#4}
    \draw[
      ->,
      \IfBooleanT{#1}{dashed},
      style/.expanded=\IfValueT{#3}{\clist_item:nn{#3}{\i}}]
      (\clist_item:nn{#5}{\i}-x)
       to node[
         sloped,
         auto=left,
         style/.expanded=\IfValueT{#2}{\clist_item:nn{#2}{\i}}]{\(\VALUE\)}
      (\clist_item:nn{#5}{\i+1}-x);
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1-x) at (0, 0) {1}; \node (2-x) at (1, 1) {2};
\node (3-x) at (2, 1) {3}; \node (4-x) at (1,-1) {4};

\graphEdge{A,B}{1,2,3}
\graphEdge*[', {blue, '}][, bend right]{C,D}{1,4,3}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

Here's the same example with the `graphs` library, unfortunatley I ran into [a bug where `name suffix` does not consider the target node properly](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1251). The proposed fix is included in the code below.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, quotes}
\tikzset{math node/.style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$}}
\makeatletter % https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1251#issuecomment-1486886842
\def\tikz@@to@or@edge@@coordinate(#1){\tikz@scan@one@point\tikz@to@use@last@coordinate@as@target(#1)\tikz@to@or@edge@function}
\def\tikz@to@use@last@coordinate@as@target#1{\iftikz@shapeborder\edef\tikztotarget{\tikz@shapeborder@name}\else\edef\tikztotarget{\the\tikz@lastx,\the\tikz@lasty}\fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\graphEdges[2][]{%
\path[name suffix=-x,#1]graph[
  use existing nodes,edge quotes={sloped,auto=left,math node}]{#2};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1-x) at (0, 0) {1}; \node (2-x) at (1, 1) {2};
\node (3-x) at (2, 1) {3}; \node (4-x) at (1,-1) {4};

\graphEdges{
  1 ->["A"]     2 ->["B"]     3,
  {[edge = dashed]
    1 ->["C"' bend right] 4 ->["D"' blue] 3,
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, i have heard about the programming interface but this is my first contact with it. Thanks!